# Example of Elliptic curve Affine compression point

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am start learning about Elliptic curve and I read about Compression multipoint in curve which will be more efficient for saving more memory, I am looking for an example I can follow it with correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Compression multipoint"* is not common terminology. Compressing multiple points is usually done by compressing each point one after another, using *point compression*. That's how I'll read the question.

For the curve $y^2\equiv x^3+a\,x+b\pmod p$ with $p=23$, $a=1$, $b=1$ of [that course](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/%7Echouinar/Handout_CSI4138_ECC_2002.pdf), a method of point compression could be to express a point as $\bigl((x\bmod p),((y\bmod p)\bmod 2)\bigr)$, which is a pair of integers with the first one in $[0,p)$ and the second either $0$ or $1$. That's compressed in the sense that a single bit is used for the second integer. E.g. point $(x,y)=(7,11)$ becomes $(7,1)$

To get back at the uncompressed form, we take $x$ (here $x=7$ from the first part of the compressed form) and use the curve's equation to compute $s\gets x^3+a\,x+b\bmod p$ (here $s=7^3+7+1\bmod23=6$), then solve for $y$ the equation $y^2\equiv s\pmod p$. We can use the method [there](https://www.rieselprime.de/ziki/Modular_square_root). In our example $p\bmod4=3$ thus one solution (if there is one) must be $y=s^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$ and (if that's not $0$) the other is $p-y$. We select the appropriate $y$ thanks to the known $y\bmod 2$ (from the second part of the compressed form), then check that indeed $y^2\bmod p=s$. Here this gives $y=6^6\bmod 23=12$ or $y=23-12=11$, we select the second one since $11\bmod2=1$, and indeed $11^2\bmod23=6$. We are back at $(x,y)=(7,11)$.

For the standardized form of point compression, see [this](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.4).

Comment: Excellent work and well explaining! So Compression point purpose is to save in memory size and not reduce the multiplication process in scalar algorithm. Right? So it's for if `y` coordinates has big size and need to reduce the size then we can use compression point! I am not sue if I am right or not?

Comment: @Cisco Saeed: yes this is right. Notice that the form of compression in my answer is not the rather unusual one in the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TC.2007.47) for your [other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/104132/555), which compresses a pair of points (rather than one point, or two point separately), compresses less (by -33.3% rather than -49.9%), but allows a noticeably faster decompression.

Comment: Yes I got the idea, but why in Khabbazian paper mentioned double compression can reduce the number of multiplications, what does it mean? what I understand maybe he meant that the compression of long `y coordinates` size will speed up the process which make it faster rather than reduce the number of multiplication process it self.

Comment: They _"reduce the required number of point doublings"_, but in their application to public key certificate that's at the cost of two or more points rather than one, thus larger size. That increase in size (their _"bandwidth"_) is mitigated by their compression, but only partially. Their compression does _"reduce the decompression cost"_ compared to the compression in the present answer, where the $s^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$ step requires a lot of field multiplications.