# How to use Double Compression point with scalar Double-and-Add in Elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

refer to this paper [Khabbazian Paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4079514) I am trying to use double point compression in scalar for example double-and-add with `k=27` which need to reduce the multiplications process for example scalar double-and-add algo consumes 4 doubling and 3 addition for `P1(3,10)` based on this example [example](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/%7Echouinar/Handout_CSI4138_ECC_2002.pdf)

I am thinking to take two points P1(3,10) P2(7,12) and compress to get P3(x1,x2,y1+y2) `P3(3,7,22)`which will be represent it in extra bit 0 because 22 is even number.

I don't know how this double compression point can reduce the number of multiplications process for `K=27` or it's considered just as compress the point to save more space in memory?

Comment: It based on this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3049465_Double_Point_Compression_with_Applications_to_Speeding_Up_Random_Point_Multiplication

Comment: The question's P1 and P2 are for curve $y^2\equiv x^3+a\,x+b\pmod p$ with $p=23$, $a=1$, $b=1$ of [that course](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/%7Echouinar/Handout_CSI4138_ECC_2002.pdf). Independently: the question refers to [that paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TC.2007.47)'s _"Double Point Compression"_ representing two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as three field elements and a bit, usually $(x_1,x_2,y_1+y_2)$ (the bit distinguishes another exceptional encoding; the question gets that bit wrong). That compression is _not_ the [standard one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/104140/555).